# How to connect my mining pool to another mining pool

Tags: mining-pools

What are some ways to connect my mining pool to another mining pool without altering any settings on the miners?

Comment: What effect are you trying to get?

Comment: I want to set up a pool that allows people to connect to it and then be able to outsource their mining power to another pool.

Comment: Your question and title are a bit unclear, we're gonna have a hard time getting you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Outsourcing to a larger pool is definitely possible and can help reduce variance. Conceptually, to them you're just a very large miner. On your side, instead of submitting a found block directly to the network, you submit it to the larger pool, and any shares you accept can be passed on the larger pool. (Regarding difficulty settings: Having different difficulty settings between your miners and the larger pool is find *as long as* the larger pool's difficulty does not exceed that of any of your miners. If that is the case, you must either bring down the difficulty of your miners or convince the larger pool operator to raise your difficulty (which they may very well agree to, since it reduces the load on their stratum).

For the actual implementation, I'd talk to someone who's done it before. [TradeMyBit](https://pool.trademybit.com/) outsources its LTC and DOGE mining to [MultiPool](https://www.multipool.us/). I've talked to the owner merc before, and he seems like a nice guy. You could try contacting him [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=203871) to see if he's willing to give you any tips.